# Mod_rewrite behavior in Ruby on Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm upgrading an app from Rails 2.3.9 to Rails 3.1.  The app has a few hundred hardcoded references to "/images/" for image assets, however due to Heroku limitations the application cannot be over 100 MB, meaning I cannot serve those assets both from /app/assets/images and /public/images.  So I need to have urls like this:

```
/images/(.*)
```

redirect to

```
/assets/$1
```

where (.*) and $1 are regex syntax - since images are generated using the image_tag syntax, css background-image syntax, and

How do I do this?  I don't think Heroku has any ways to do it outside rails, but I could be wrong.  Is this something to define in routes.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rack-rewrite: https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite